# Bind a event on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

What is the best way to bind an event on multiple element .
I wrote this code to do that is there is any good way to do that.

```
$('#GiftPurchase_recipient_first_name,#GiftPurchase_recipient_last_name').bind('blur', function() {
        gift_to  = $('#GiftPurchase_recipient_first_name').val()+" "+$('#GiftPurchase_recipient_last_name').val();
        $("#gift_to").val(gift_to);
    });
```

I have two input box with first name and last name, i wont to display there first anme and last name into a another element

Comment: Apart the missing `var`, what's the problem with your code ?

Comment: Some time it not bind my event

Comment: whether the elements are created dynamically?

Comment: Yes this element are created by yii framework lib and i use this code inside $( document ).ready(function() {}) function

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements a class and add the event to the class.

```
$('.theclassnamethatalltheelementsshare').bind('blur', function() {
    gift_to  = $('#GiftPurchase_recipient_first_name').val()+""+$('#GiftPurchase_recipient_last_name').val();
    $("#gift_to").val(gift_to);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#GiftPurchase_recipient_first_name,#GiftPurchase_recipient_last_name').bind('blur',function(){
        var gift_to  = $('#GiftPurchase_recipient_first_name').val()+" "+$('#GiftPurchase_recipient_last_name').val();
        $("#gift_to").val(gift_to);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6J3H/1/)